# How can I filter row in DataTable Using C#

Tags: c#, dataview

I need filter in my Row side so how to set using dataview i need set only filtered record in datatable .
Ex : if i have three types of record available in datatable and i want to filter one of them so what should i do??

DataView dv = dtsrc.DefaultView;
                    dv.RowFilter = "what's the sintex should i give here"
????

Comment: **Guys I have Found Solution For that like Following** ....
**And its Working properly**

   DataView dv = dtsrc.DefaultView;
    dv.RowFilter = "[TransactionType] LIKE '%" + TransactionType + "%'";
    DataTable dtNew = dv.ToTable();
    My_DataTable = dtNew;

We can Get Filtered Data in to My_DataTable!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `DataView.RowFilter` like this :

```
dv.RowFilter = "Col < 3";
```

Check this link : 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/enus/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter(v=vs.110).aspx

You can also use `linq` statement which I recommend :

```
DataTable orders = dataSet.Tables["SalesOrderHeader"];

EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> query =
    from order in orders.AsEnumerable()
    where order.Field<bool>("OnlineOrderFlag") == true
    orderby order.Field<decimal>("TotalDue")
    select order;

DataView view = query.AsDataView();

bindingSource1.DataSource = view;
```

Check this link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score -1):

I think this is usefull for you
http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/

```
dataView.RowFilter = "Num = 10"             // number is equal to 10
dataView.RowFilter = "Date < #1/1/2008#"    // date is less than 1/1/2008
dataView.RowFilter = "Name <> 'John'"       // string is not equal to 'John'
dataView.RowFilter = "Name >= 'Jo'"         // string comparison
```

Comment: Dude I have Found Solution For that like Following ....
And its Working properly .

    DataView dv = dtsrc.DefaultView;
    dv.RowFilter = "[TransactionType] LIKE '%" + TransactionType + "%'";
    DataTable dtNew = dv.ToTable();

                    My_DataTable = dtNew;

We can Get Filtered Data in to My_DataTable!

Answer (score -2):

dv.RowFilter = "Deptno=" + comboBox1.SelectedItem;

You may take reference from here:

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/231800/Syntax-of-Rowfilter-in-DataView-In-Csharp